# issue with back quotes inside while loop when running a command over ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, quoting, command-substitution

This question is a bit complicated. I will try to explain in detail.

I have two machines, one is local and other say `192.168.1.2`. I have set the following variables in my local machine

`CHECK="/home/test/Desktop/"`

There exists a user named `test` in both my local machine as well as remote  machine. I want to run the following command from my local over ssh.

```
ssh -n test@192.168.1.2 "until [ `cat $CHECK/samplefile | grep "string"` ]; do touch  $CHECK/success; done"
```

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to check the $CHECK/samplefile for the entry named "string" in my remote machine. Once it is found I want to exit the `until` loop and go further. But when I run this command I get the following error message.

`cat: /home/test/Desktop//samplefile: No such file or directory`

But I am pretty sure that my remote machine contain file name samplefile in `test` user's Desktop.  On a further research I came to know that the conditional statement of `until` given in backquotes actually run at `local` instead of `remote` (My local doesn't contain such a file in Desktop). Also, the rest of the commands inside until loop works fine and a new file named success is created in remote machine's Desktop.

I am not sure whether the issue is with backquotes or until. I have been stuck on this for the past 3 hours. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed in your question, this substitution:

```
`cat $CHECK/samplefile | grep "string"`
```

was executed at your local machine. You can fix it easily this way:

```
ssh -n test@192.168.1.2 \
"until { cat ""$CHECK""/samplefile | grep ""string""; }; do \
touch  ""$CHECK""/success; \
done"
```

As you can see, you don't need any substitution but for resolving the `$CHECK` variable. You can put the conditional instructions into a `{...}` list and the now the list's exit code is decisive for the `until` instruction.

Comment: I get `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
bash: -c: line 0: `until { cat /home/test/Desktop//samplefile | grep string }; do touch  /home/test/Desktop//success; done'`

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus Sorry, I forgot about the `;` at the end of the list in braces. It should be ok now.

Comment: You could use the single quotes inside the double like as follows: `"until < '$CHECK/samplefile' grep 'string'; do touch '$CHECK/success'; done"` since now that the backquotes have been taken out of the picture.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it's the quoting.  By using double-quotes to wrap your remote command in, you're telling your local shell to interpret whatever it can to pass to the ssh session.  In this case, the `cat` command.

If you wrap your command in single quotes, you won't have that problem, but you also won't be able to expand variables that were defined outside the single quotes.

local file:

```
bash-[501]$ echo $(hostname) > /tmp/samplefile
bash-[506]$ echo $(cat /tmp/samplefile)
tank
```

create the remote file:

```
bash-[502]$ ssh evil 'echo $(hostname) > /tmp/samplefile'
bash-[501]$ cat /tmp/samplefile
evil
```

try to view the remote file with double-quotes:

```
bash-[508]$ ssh evil "echo `cat /tmp/samplefile`"
tank
```

try to view the remote file with single quotes:

```
bash-[509]$ ssh evil 'echo `cat /tmp/samplefile`'
evil
```

define the file as a variable to be processed on the remote side:

```
bash-[527]$ ssh evil 'F=/tmp/samplefile; cat $F'
evil
```

In your case, wrapping the command in single quotes, and defining `$CHECK` inside those quotes, out to be enough to send everything to be interpreted at the remote side.

```
ssh -n test@192.168.1.2 'CHECK=/home/test/Desktop; until [ `cat $CHECK/samplefile | grep "string"` ]; do touch  $CHECK/success; done'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export CHECK='/home/test/Desktop'
ssh -n test@192.168.1.2 'until [ `cat "$CHECK/samplefile" | grep "string"` ]; do touch  "$CHECK/success"; done'
```